# How to diagnose "Warning: Active APKs support fewer devices than previously active APKs. Some users will not receive updates"

Tags: android

I updated an app on the market, and got this error:

Warning: Active APKs support fewer devices than previously active APKs. Some users will not receive updates

However, I can't think of anything I changed that would cause this.  Mostly I added a bunch of new styles and drawables.

Is there any way to determine what devices are excluded from an apk?

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out.  The market added the "touchscreen" permission to my app implicitly.  That probably triggered the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change anything on the app's manifest file? This usually occurs when you add a permission to the app. Try checking your  tags...

Comment: Yes, the manifest was the first thing I checked.  Maybe I'd better double-check it.  Stand by...

Answer (score 0):

If you have not edited your AndroidManifest.xml, this should not happen. You can check the uploaded manifest by downloading the apk and extracting it, if you didn't use version control, or didn't flag your commit as "uploaded".

Comment: That's a new concept to me -- what do you mean by flagging a commit as "uploaded"?

Comment: If you're using a version control system, you have the chance to label each commit. It is useful to add labels to mark milestones like RC1, beta, release v1 and so in.

Comment: Got it. Yes, I use Subversion, and am very careful to tag every release. I even tag the libraries it uses.